# Group by with priority of column value over other row in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a database table like below.
[image]

Here I am using group by on parent_sku column. Here is my query and its result.
[image]

```
SELECT
  domain,
  parent,
  parent_name,
  parent_sku,
  SUM(qty)        AS sales,
  SUM(gross)      AS revenue,
  SUM(net)        AS net_revenue,
  SUM(refund_qty) AS returns,
  created_at
FROM report_byproducts_name
GROUP BY parent_sku
ORDER BY sales DESC
LIMIT 50
```

But I want to give priority for the domain name. Like if I give priority to themusthaves domain then it should give the result as `domain = themusthaves and parent = 450212` with the same group by.
Currently, I am always getting `domain=tmhde` and `parent=325227`

**Expected Result**
[image]

**Note: Please ignore created_at column**

Any suggestions will be appreciated

Thanks

Here I am adding [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/87449d/5)

Comment: If you want to `group by` multiple columns, then add multiple columns to your `group by`, separated by commas.

Comment: @smcjones: I don't want to group by multiple columns. I just want to set the priority of themusthaves domain at the top over other domain column

Comment: You want to give priority by `sales` column?

Comment: Your query is invalid because you are selecting non aggregate columns which grouping only by the `parent_sku`.  Please fix this problem first before proceeding.

Comment: @num8er: No I want to give priority to domain column so I can get domain=themusthaves and parent=450212 as a group by result.

Comment: Your logic is completely against the sql standards and only succeeds in your mysql server because the only full group by sql mode is turned off.

Comment: guys if his logic is against (I also agree) let's write a response where he can achieve his goals, agree?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Actually I don't want domain column. its just for information I want parent based on the particular domain when I do a group by parent_sku.

Comment: Let him first share his real table structure as `SHOW CREATE TABLE [table]`  and some example data as ascii data table or as sqlfiddle.com (not as images).. Also let him provide the expected results as a ascii data table..

Comment: @RakeshSojitra I think You've overcomplicated Your question. You just want to get best sold product for domain. So check my answer.

Comment: @num8er: I just edited my question with expected sales result of all domain so not only themusthaves. I want to set priority to themusthaves domain only but want all group by results

Comment: @RakeshSojitra You don't need to group, You need to sort by some field and then extract it using some interpreter

Comment: I just removed extra where conditions to overcome of confusions

Comment: So You want summary per product + You want detailed sell stats by seller. You've to use interpreter and sort it out or mysql stored function. Otherwise have to make 2 requests: 1 for summary, 1 for getting seller's sale stats.

Comment: @num8er: can you tell me how can I do in a single MySQL query? because I have lots of data and I don't want to go through a loop.

Comment: it's not looping, it's sending 1 request to get sum and another is to get sale using parent array generated from 1 query and loading using `parent IN (1,2,3...)`  - it's called eager loading and then sorting results using interpreter

Comment: And what about a parent column? I hope you have viewed my expected result screenshot properly.

Comment: step1: `query is to get top 50 records grouped by some field`, step2: `loop array of results and have comma separated string of grouped field`, step3: `do same query as 1st query but without grouping` and or etc. better to have some php code or something alike to work on it.

Comment: @RaymondNijland : I have added SQL fiddle for you

Comment: For some reason the sqlfiddle link isn't loading..

Comment: @RaymondNijland: It's loading correctly can you please try again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the support. I can get the expected results using the subquery like below. I don't know the way is correct or not but I am posting my answer here through which I can get expected results. Through I will wait for the better suggestions to get expected results.

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT domain FROM report_byproducts_name WHERE domain='themusthaves' AND parent_sku=rbn.parent_sku) as domain,
  (SELECT parent FROM report_byproducts_name WHERE domain='themusthaves' AND parent_sku=rbn.parent_sku) as parent,
  parent_name,
  parent_sku, 
  SUM(sales) as sales, 
  SUM(revenue) as revenue, 
  SUM(net_revenue) as net_revenue, 
  SUM(returns) as returns,
  created_at 
FROM report_byproducts_name rbn 
GROUP by parent_sku 
ORDER BY sales DESC 
LIMIT 50
```

Here is [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/87449d/24) for the expected results

Comment: I would not trust the group by- If ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is disabled, a MySQL extension to the standard SQL use of GROUP BY permits the select list, HAVING condition, or ORDER BY list to refer to nonaggregated columns even if the columns are not functionally dependent on GROUP BY columns. This causes MySQL to accept the preceding query. In this case, the server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are nondeterministic, which is probably not what you want. - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: @P.Salmon: Thanks for the information. This query might be invalid with ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY enabled because of the nonaggregated domain, parent etc columns. But how can I get expected result for this type of table structure? Any other way?

Comment: Did you look at my answer?

Comment: @P.Salmon: Yes I have checked answer where you have used max(parent) but I can't use it as max(parent) because parent column is the relational column which is dependent on the domain. I want data based on the current domain. so if current domain is tmhde then I want parent based on tmhde, if current domain is themusthaves then I want parent based on themustahves domain and so on. In my answer I can pass current domain as parameter

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to aggregate a few more columns then join back to your table to get the relevant non aggregate columns something like

```
   select domain,
         parent,
         parent_name,parent_sku,
         sumsales,sumrevenue,sumnet_revenue,sumreturns
from report_byproducts_name
Join
(
SELECT
  max(parent) maxparent,
  parent_sku aggsparent_sku,
  SUM(sales)        AS sumsales,
  SUM(revenue)      AS sumrevenue,
  SUM(net_revenue)  AS sumnet_revenue,
  SUM(returns) AS sumreturns
FROM report_byproducts_name
GROUP BY parent_sku
) aggs on aggs.maxparent = parent and aggs.aggsparent_sku = parent_sku;

+--------------+--------+--------------------------------+------------+----------+-------------------+-------------------+------------+
| domain       | parent | parent_name                    | parent_sku | sumsales | sumrevenue        | sumnet_revenue    | sumreturns |
+--------------+--------+--------------------------------+------------+----------+-------------------+-------------------+------------+
| themusthaves | 450212 | Pailletten Damaged Jeans Grijs | 311        |      350 | 13692.89013671875 | 11360.31005859375 |          1 |
+--------------+--------+--------------------------------+------------+----------+-------------------+-------------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Can I suggest you change float fields to decimal(10,2).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by creating `temp` table. Here is what you can do:

```
WITH temp AS
(
SELECT
  parent_sku,
  SUM(qty)        AS sales,
  SUM(gross)      AS revenue,
  SUM(net)        AS net_revenue,
  SUM(refund_qty) AS returns,
  created_at
FROM report_byproducts_name
GROUP BY parent_sku
)
SELECT * FROM report_byproducts_name
WHERE parent_sku IN (SELECT parent_sku FROM temp) AND domain = 'themusthaves'
```

You can give priority in Where clause.

Comment: Will only work in MySQL 8.0+ because that's the only version that supports CTE.. And it's unliky the topicstarter is using MySQL 8.0 because it's not production ready jet.